# Changing value conditionally only for numerical variables in dataframe

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

Imagine I have a dataframe. This dataframe consists of numerical and non-numerical variables.
For all the numerical variables I would like to operate the following:

IF the value is bigger than the mean of the column it is in then change the value to "high".

ELSE change it to "low".

I have come very close to the solution with the following line of code:

```
df <- mutate_if(df, is.numeric, funs(ifelse(. > mean(.), "high", "low")))
```

However, I am aware that the `mean(.)` part is incorrect. So my question is:

How can I correct this part so I get the mean of the corresponding variable where `.` is in?

Also, I am assuming the rest is correct. If this is not the case I would appreciate someone telling me so I can try to correct it!

Here is an illustration of what I am trying to achieve:

```
duration amount sex 
6        2      F
5        2      M
3        9      M 
2        3      M
```

should become:

```
duration   amount   sex 
high       low      F
high       low      M
low        high     M 
low        low      M
```

EDIT:

The accepted answer made me realize my code was correct in the end!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the newer version of `dplyr` (version `>= 1.0`), we use `mutate` with `across` as the suffix `if`, `at` `all` are getting deprecated

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
      mutate(across(where(is.numeric), 
        ~ case_when(. > mean(., na.rm = TRUE) ~ "high", TRUE ~ "low")))
```

-output

```
#  duration amount sex
#1     high    low   F
#2     high    low   M
#3      low   high   M
#4      low    low   M
```

Or with `ifelse`

```
df %>%
      mutate(across(where(is.numeric), 
        ~ ifelse(. > mean(., na.rm = TRUE), "high", "low")))
```

---

Or using the previous version

```
df %>%
     mutate_if(is.numeric, ~ ifelse(. > mean(.), "high", "low"))
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(duration = c(6L, 5L, 3L, 2L), amount = c(2L, 2L, 
9L, 3L), sex = c("F", "M", "M", "M")), class = "data.frame",
row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

Comment: You just made me realize my code was correct indeed. Thank you.

Comment: @jxpython it is actually giving error on my dplyr version.  Please note the `~` I inserted and `funs` is deprecated

Comment: Also if you change funs to .funs?

Comment: @jxpython Because of the deprecation of functions in different version, it is hard to know whether your original code works on your version vs my code on the old dplyr version

Comment: @jxpython yes, you can do that, also can wrap in a `list` as well